# Did Ruth sleep with her father?

Tags: toni-morrison, song-of-solomon-morrison

I'm reading Toni Morrison's Song of Solomon, and I'm also confused by this question. Macon, Ruth's husband, claims that Ruth had sex with her dead father:

> “In the bed,” he said, and stopped for so long Milkman was not sure he was going to continue. “In the bed. That's where she was when I opened the door. Laying next to him. Naked as a yard dog, kissing him. Him dead and white and puffy and skinny, and she had his fingers in her mouth.

Ruth claims that she didn't:

> Milkman leaned his head against the cold handbar that was attached to the seat in front of him. He held it there, letting its chill circle his head. Then he turned to his mother. “Were you father when he was dead? Naked?”
>
> “No. But I did kneel there in my slip at his bedside and kiss his beautiful fingers. They were the only part of him that wasn't…”

Who is right?

Comment: These two are not mutually incompatible. I can see why you think the first quote implies sex, but it's a very loose association - it feels more valid just to take the description at face value. If you do that, the only disassociation between them is that one claims Ruth is naked and the other that she was in her slip.